# How to handle mailer daemon responses with JavaMail API and exchange server?

Tags: jakarta-mail, exchange-server, email-bounces, verp

We have a mailing service, where we send notifications to users. But when a user's email is invalid , the the server responds with a mailer daemon response or bounce mail. I want to catch these responses and log them into a database.
Is this possible using JavaMail API along with exchange mail server.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This [JavaMail FAQ](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#bounce) entry should help.

Comment: Thanks, I have gone through that but did not find perfect answer

Comment: There is no perfect answer.  If there's some specific part you're stuck on, ask a more specific question.

Comment: Thanks I have updated my question with more details

Comment: You didn't really add more details, you just made the question more general.  The simple answer to your question is yes, it's possible, but not perfectly so.  There are some cases where the email address will be invalid and you won't be notified, and some cases where the notification will be sent to the wrong address.  If that's "good enough", then do what the FAQ says.  If you think you need a perfect solution, there is none.

Comment: Thanks . After some R& D, we found that exchange server doesn't support VERP